# CUPS: issues with two Brother USB printers (different model)

Tags: usb, cups

I finally managed to get one printer working as it was shown propoerly as "usb://Brother/QL-500?serial=123456789"

I am using CUPS 2.3.3op2, I installed printer-driver-ptouch and printer-driver-all

Next to my QL500, I also connected a PT-P700 via usb, b ut this one is not recognized by CUPS

lsusb shows
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 04f9:2015 Brother Industries, Ltd QL-500 label printer
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 04f9:2064 Brother Industries, Ltd PT-P700 P-touch Label Printer RemovableDisk

any idea?

PS: trying to use both with Windows10 PCs (QL500 works, PT700 not (as not even recognized in CUPS))